# OAuth for a Stack Exchange API library?

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

I use [the *stackr* library](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) for the Stack Exchange API.

I have registered my API and have the credentials.

In [the documentation](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) it refers that it is possible to use a general auth.

What kind of commands should I include to use the API in a code like this:

```
library(stackr)
questions <- stack_users(9371451, "questions", num_pages=10, pagesize=100, filter="withbody")
for (i in 1:nrow(questions)) {
    qtext <- questions$body[i]
    print(qtext)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation for that library under "Future Plans"](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr#user-content-future-plans).  It clearly states:

> Currently, **no methods requiring authentication are implemented.** OAuth 2.0 could be implemented through the same httr framework ([see here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html)), but my current judgment is that R is likely to be used for data analysis operations rather than actual front-ends for Stack Exchange, which negates the need for most authentication-based operations.

What that means is, **the *stackr* library does not support authentication** and the author doesn't plan to add it any time soon.

You **can't just add parameters** to your `questions <- stack_users()` code<sup>†</sup> because **[authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) requires a special round-robin exchange that that library is not set up to handle.**

You would have to fork that library in GitHub and add the methods yourself.

---

<sup>†</sup> Well, technically you *could* add an `access_token` parameter, but getting one keyed to your app would be a cumbersome manual process which is beyond the scope of this question (you'd be much smarter to fork the library or use a different one).